# MSSQL query for all records between two date range of current day

Tags: sql, sql-server

I might not be asking this right, but basically I need a query that when ran, returns all records entered from the 1st till the 15th of the current month. And when the 15 passes only return the records from the 16th till the end of the current month.

I've tried to build something like this but its for bigquery and not sql, and I can't seem to find something similar for mssql 2016.

```
select sample_id
from dbo.table
WHERE date_entered BETWEEN DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), -15, 'DAY') AND CURRENT_DATE()
or
WHERE date_entered BETWEEN CAST(eomonth(GETDATE()) AS datetime) AND CURRENT_DATE()
```

Regardless of the today's date, I need the 1st till today, until the 15th. Then the 16th till today, until the end of the month. Sorry I'm new to SQL.

UPDATE: I was able to solve this issue with the example provided by @GordonLinoff . Thank you Gordon!

```
SELECT rowguid, ModifiedDate 
FROM [AdventureWorks2017].[Person].[Person]
WHERE Year(ModifiedDate) =Year(getdate()) and month(ModifiedDate) =month(getdate()) and 
((day(getdate()) <= 15 and day(ModifiedDate) <=15))
Or
((day(getdate()) >= 16 and day(ModifiedDate) >=16))
```

Comment: . . You have tagged the question Google BigQuery.  But your code will not run in that database.  It uses SQL Server/Sybase functions.  Please elaborate on the database you are using.

Comment: I apologize, I am using SQL server 2016.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The description of your logic is a bit hard to follow, but you seem to want something like this:

```
where date_entered >= datefromparts(year(getdate(), month(getdate(), 1)) and -- this month
      (day(getdate()) <= 15 or
       day(getdate()) > 15 and day(date_entered) > 15
      )
```

Comment: Gordon, thank you. This looks like what I may need but how do i use date_from_parts? Do I replace that with DATEFROMPARTS ?

Comment: @LunaBerm . . . That was a typo.

Comment: Thank you Gordon, your answer was able to send me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

This was MySQL:

```
  SELECT *
  FROM dbo.table
  WHERE date BETWEEN  CASE WHEN DAY(CURRENT_DATE) <= 15 
                           THEN DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE, '%Y-%m-01')
                           ELSE DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE, '%Y-%m-16')
                      END 
                AND   CASE WHEN DAY(CURRENT_DATE) <= 15 
                           THEN DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE, '%Y-%m-15')
                           ELSE LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE)
                      END
```

Big Query:

```
 SELECT *
 FROM table
 WHERE date BETWEEN  CASE WHEN EXTRACT(DAY FROM CURRENT_DATE) <= 15 
                          THEN DATE_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE, MONTH)
                          ELSE DATE_ADD(DATE_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE, MONTH), INTERVAL 15 DAY) 
                     END 
               AND   CASE WHEN EXTRACT(DAY FROM CURRENT_DATE) <= 15 
                          THEN DATE_ADD(DATE_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE, MONTH), INTERVAL 14 DAY) 
                          ELSE DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 31 DAY) 
                     END
```

This should give

```
    date between 1 and 15
or  date between 16 and last_of_the_month
```

Answer (score 0):

> I've tried to build something like this but its for bigquery

*Whatever example you use - it is not working in BigQuery either!*

Below is working example for BigQuery Standard SQL and uses some "tricks" to avoid using redundant code fragments

```
#standardSQL
SELECT sample_id
FROM `project.dataset.table`, 
UNNEST([STRUCT(
  EXTRACT(DAY FROM date_entered) AS day, 
  DATE_TRUNC(date_entered, MONTH) AS month
)])  
WHERE DATE_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(), MONTH) = month 
AND IF(
    EXTRACT(DAY FROM CURRENT_DATE()) < 16, 
    day BETWEEN 1 AND 15,
    day BETWEEN 16 AND 99
  )
```

Comment: not `CURRENT_DATE()` instead is `date_entered`  `EXTRACT(DAY FROM date_entered BETWEEN 1 AND 15,` ??

Comment: Thank you Mikhail, but I only used bigquery as an example. How can I use one of your queries in MSSQL 2016?

Comment: Luna that wasnt what you ask, you should fix your question

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza - thank yo for checking - obviously typos - fixed now

Comment: Juan - you're right, I did not ask correctly. I tried to update it to be more specific.